# How to solve resistance in this kind of circuit?

Tags: resistors

[image]

I want to find the resistance value between A and B.

I thought the solution would be ( // = for parallel, I'd like to avoid tons of ugly divisions):

\$Rab = [(R1+R5+R4) // (R3+R4)] // [(R3+R5+R2)//(R1+R2)] \$

But I checked with some random values and it didn't work, or maybe I miss typed something  ?

EDIT: Just to clarify, these resistors don't have any values, ignore "R"

Comment: Wye-delta conversion.

Comment: From 2 seconds inspection, we can see the solution is R.  In this special case, think about the voltage across R5, which also tells you the current thru it.  With that, a major simplification is possible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Just googled this and found the way to do it thanks ! (I searched before but I didn't know the name of this circuit sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the voltage difference between A and B, because R1 and R2 are equal the voltage at the R1 R5 R2 junction will be half  of that difference.

Then, since R3 and R4 are equal, the voltage at the R3 R5 R4 junction will also be half of the voltage difference between A and B.

Since the voltage across the ends of R5 will therefore be equal, no charge will flow through R5 and it vanishes from the circuit.

Then, since R1 and R2 are in series their total resistance will be 2R and, since R3 and R4 are in series, their total resistance will also be 2R.

Finally, since 2R is connected in parallel with 2R the total resistance seen from A to B will be half of 2R, or R.

For a more in-depth treatment, Google "Wheatstone bridge"

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this before  but there is no values (ignore "R")

Comment: We can't ignore "R". R has to be some value, and as drawn, all R's are identical. So if all of the resistors are the same value, whatever that is ("R"), then the above holds true. It does not, if the R's are different values.

Answer (score 0):

Related closely to Em Field's answer and Olin's comment,my answer will tell you this:your calculations serve no purpose(they're overcomplicated).Due to the wheatstone bridge method,R5 is taken out of the equation from the start,because the ratio R2/R1 is equal to the ratio R4/R3 there is no potential diferrence between R5's nodes,thus the current flowing through the resistor is null.Pretend it doesn't exist in the scheme.The rest is not hard at all.R1 is in series with R2,R3 with R4,etc.The equivalent resistance is:(R1+R2)(R3+R4)/(R1+R2+R3+R4).